# Implementing String join function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and trying to implement a function that takes a separator and a list to return a concatenated string (Similar to join function in Python)

```
strJoin sep arr = case arr of
  [] -> ""
  (x : xs) -> x ++ sep ++ strJoin sep xs
```

When I call this function `strJoin "|" ["foo", "bar"]` it prints `"foo|bar|"` even though I'd like result to read `"foo|bar"`

How can I adjust my pattern match code so that it work differently for the last element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in that last line of your code:

```
(x : xs) -> x ++ sep ++ strJoin sep xs
```

The meaning of the pattern `x : xs` is that `x` will match with a single element, namely the first element of the list, and `xs` will match with a list, namely the list of all elements except the first one. This list can be empty. Specifically, if `arr` contains a single element then `x` will match with that single element and `xs` will match with the rest of the list, which is the empty list. But then, on the right hand side, you effectively have:

```
x ++ sep ++ strJoin sep []
```

which is equivalent to

```
x ++ sep ++ ""
```

which in turn is the same as

```
x ++ sep
```

This explains the behavior of your function. So how can we fix that? One solution is to try to change the pattern for that case so that the rule is not used on a list with a single element. One way to do that is like so:

```
(x : xs @ (_ : _)) -> x ++ sep ++ strJoin sep xs
```

Here `xs @ (_ : _)` will match with a nonempty list. I will leave the explanation of that as an exercise.
So now that rule will not be used on single element lists, as we wanted, but the problem is that there is no rule for such lists anymore. So we need to add a new one. The following will do:

```
[x] -> x
```

So putting it all together:

```
strJoin sep arr = case arr of
    [] -> ""
    (x : xs @ (_ : _)) -> x ++ sep ++ strJoin sep xs
    [x] -> x
```

Of course there are many other ways to do this, here's one:

```
strJoin sep arr = case arr of
    [] -> ""
    [x] -> x
    (x : xs) -> x ++ sep ++ strJoin sep xs
```

I'll leave it as an exercise how this works.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. I'm seeing @ for the first time, I'm going to find the explanation of how that works. Btw your second solution is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your solution is that the second pattern also matches elements with one element (in which case `xs` is `[]`), so you will have one extra recursive call.

```
strJoin sep arr = case arr of
  [] -> ""
  ([x]) -> x   
  (x : xs) -> x ++ sep ++ strJoin sep xs
```

If you don't want to build this yourself for learning purposes, `Data.List` has `intercalate` for this purpose:

https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=intercalate

```
import Data.List 

intercalate "|" ["foo", "bar"]
```

Or you could use `concat` and `intersperse` together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm curious to know if this can this be done using pattern matching.

Comment: I added an answer for you.

Comment: @MichaelKohl Thanks for adding a solution using pattern matching. I marked redneb's solution as the answer because of all the explanation he added. Thanks again for telling me about the intercalate function.

Comment: I googled to find the source of Data.List and intercalate function  (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/src/Data-List.html) and realized that it is implemented very similar to answers I have received here :-)

Comment: I think the above causes `strJoin "|" ["foo"] = "foo|"` which I don't think it is the expected output. The base case should be 1, not 2, IMO.

Comment: Thanks @chi, I fixed the pattern.